# How to fix an issue while build android app in ionic?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I've got an issue while use ionic cordova build android .
How to fix " Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'. > Android resource linking failed authenticator.xml:2: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/icon (aka io.ionic.starter:mipmap/icon) not found. 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

  > Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
  >   Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
  >   Android resource linking failed
  >   C:\ES.eWarrant\eWarrant\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\authenticator.xml:2: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/icon (aka io.ionic.starter:mipmap/icon) not found.

  error: failed linking file resources.

Comment: is this ionic 3 or 4? If ionic 3 sounds like your icons are being generated to the wrong directory. Does ionic `ionic cordova resources` work ?

Comment: @IraW its ionic 4...now i built my app...but i cant install it anywhere... I dunno why.

Answer (score 6):

After spending hours and hours on this, finally found the proper way to fix it for my IONIC 5 project.

Step 1.

Create a image file named `icon.png`, inside your `resources` folder.

Step 2.

Add this line to your `CONFIG.XML` file, under `<platform name="android">` tag.

```
<resource-file src="resources/icon.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap/icon.png" />
```

Step 3.

Then,
remove platform  :  `ionic cordova platform rm android`

add platform  :  `ionic cordova platform add android`

prepare cordova  :  `ionic cordova prepare android`

build android  :  `ionic cordova build android`

I think this will solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! The most easy and definitive remedy to problem.

Comment: This fixed my issue, most cleanest solution

Answer (score 5):

i know this is an old topic, but if someons has this problema, i have a solution, if you use the Background Geolocation plugin from ionic native, has an issue with authenticator.xml, this uses @mipmap/icon as the resource for tha icon in the background, the way that i solved it was changing the vaules in the file android.json inside platforms/android, if you search for this

```
`{
"res/xml/authenticator.xml": {
        "parents": {
          "/*": [
            {
              "xml": "<account-authenticator android:accountType=\"@string/mauron85_bgloc_account_type\" android:icon=\"@mipmap/icon\" android:label=\"@string/app_name\" android:smallIcon=\"@mipmap/icon\" xmlns:android=\"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android\" />",
              "count": 1,
              "mode": "overwrite",
              "plugin": "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation",
              "oldAttrib": {
                "android:accountType": "@string/mauron85_bgloc_account_type",
                "android:icon": "@mipmap/icon",
                "android:label": "@string/app_name",
                "android:smallIcon": "@mipmap/icon",
                "xmlns:android": "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }`
```

you can change it like this

```
`
{
"res/xml/authenticator.xml": {
        "parents": {
          "/*": [
            {
              "xml": "<account-authenticator android:accountType=\"@string/mauron85_bgloc_account_type\" android:icon=\"@mipmap/ic_launcher\" android:label=\"@string/app_name\" android:smallIcon=\"@mipmap/ic_launcher\" xmlns:android=\"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android\" />",
              "count": 1,
              "mode": "overwrite",
              "plugin": "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation",
              "oldAttrib": {
                "android:accountType": "@string/mauron85_bgloc_account_type",
                "android:icon": "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
                "android:label": "@string/app_name",
                "android:smallIcon": "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
                "xmlns:android": "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}`
```

and it works like a charm

Regards

Answer (score -1):

The solution:

Just as a correction>
Create a directory: `platforms\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap`.

Then copy `resources\splash.png` to `icon.png` in the new mipmap directory.